# Error while converting PPT to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

I am trying to make a application which converts docx/xls/ppt to pdf.

1. Conversion of  docx and xls requires Microsoft.Office.core dll
2. Conversion of  ppt requires Office.dll

I successfully converted 1 and 2 separately but when i try to merge both of them i.e

when i try to add both the reference (Microsoft.Office.core dll and Office.dll) together it gives me error.

so, is there any problem in adding both the dll's ?

229 error of same Kind ---- Error   1   Cannot embed interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoBlogImageType' found in both assembly 'e:\All Pdf\waterMark_PDF\PDF Merger and Protector Source Code\PDFMerger\obj\Debug\Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core.dll' and 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Office.dll'. Consider setting the 'Embed Interop Types' property to false.

Note - i had changed "Embed Interop Types" property to false for both dll's.

please help.

Comment: what error you have? What versions are you trying to reference?

Comment: 229 error of same Kind ----     Error 1 Cannot embed interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoBlogImageType' found in both assembly 'e:\All Pdf\waterMark_PDF\PDF Merger and Protector Source Code\PDFMerger\obj\Debug\Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core.dll' and 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Office.dll'. Consider setting the 'Embed Interop Types' property to false. PDFMerger

Comment: i am using vs10 , office 2007 , Microsoft.Office.core dll and Office.dll version 12

Comment: may be go down in the errors list and see what is the last error. solving that error could manage the rest of  problems

Comment: @yogeshlawate when you have additional information about your question, please edit the question to include it instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: Make sure you are using the same version of Interop & Core. They mostly compatible, but you might have found an edge case.

Comment: well all the error says "Consider setting the 'Embed Interop Types' property to false." and i have done that already, still the same error.

Comment: Could you just use Interop?
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Comment: the problem is while opening a ppt file i use this line "PPDoc = PPApplication.Presentations.Open(input, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);"   and for Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState i need office.dll

Comment: have you fixed the issue?

Comment: no, still stuck on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the specific libraries:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Power = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
```

They should have everything you need along with not having namespace isssues between interlocking dll's

These are found as COM references

EDIT: Also, are you using correct namespaces? If you could post some code it would be helpful.

Comment: 1) My problem is not with those dll's. my problem is with Microsoft.Office.Core dll and Office.dll                             2) PowerPoint needs office.dll and other two needs Microsoft.Office.Core dll. 3)But when i add both the dll's in my references, following 229 errors get generated

Comment: "Cannot embed interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoBlogImageType' found in both assembly 'e:\All Pdf\waterMark_PDF\PDF Merger and Protector Source Code\PDFMerger\obj\Debug\Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core.dll' and 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Office.dll'. Consider setting the 'Embed Interop Types' property to false."

Comment: note - i have also set Embed Interop Types property to false for both the dll's.

Comment: I understand that you are having issues with the office.dll, but what I am saying is that you can convert word/excel/powerpoint all with the three libraries I said. Source: I wrote a program that does this.